# Validating radio elements in a form not by the name

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, radio-button

I have to validate the radio elements in a form with javascript, but I cannot do it by the name (getElementByName), for reasons that are too long to explain. I'm currently trying to validate it like this:

```
for (var i=0; i<document.forms[0].elements.length; i++){ 
element = document.forms[0].elements[i];
    if(element.checked){}
            else {alert("whatever");}
}
```

But in the form there is an element which is a button, and it counts the button when it shouldn't be a part of the radio element validation. This code doesn't validate the form. How do you select only the radio elements of a form? Like type[radio] or something like that?

Thanks in advance for your time. Agnese

Answer (score 1):

You can use `type` property of the element

```
if (element.type === 'radio' && element.checked)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this ... updating your code

```
for (var i=0; i<document.forms[0].elements.length; i++){ 
    element = document.forms[0].elements[i];
    if(element.type == "radio") {
        var isChecked = element.checked;
        alert('radio '+element.id+' is ' + isChecked);
    }
    else { continue; }
}
```